# Convert QGraphicsItem::pos() to scene coordinates

Tags: c++, qt, coordinates, qgraphicsscene, qgraphicsitem

I have a custom `QGraphicsItem` which overrides `QGraphicsItem::itemChange()` like so

```
QVariant CustomItem::itemChange(QGraphicsItem::GraphicsItemChange change, const QVariant &value)
{
    if (change == QGraphicsItem::ItemPositionChange) {
        QPointF newPos = value.toPointF();
        QRectF rect = mapRectToScene(boundingRect());

        qDebug() << "newPos" << newPos;
        qDebug() << "rect" << rect;
    }
    return QGraphicsItem::itemChange(change, value);
}
```

`newPos`'s (0, 0) is located where the item was created, while `rect`'s (0, 0) is located at the top-left corner of the scene;

I would like to convert `newPos` so it lives in the same coordinate system as `rect`.
I tried all the `mapTo` / `mapFrom` functions from `QGraphicsItem`, but nothing is working.

Could anybody help ? Thanks

Comment: newPos is not in coordinates of the item but of the scene so I do not see the conversion necessary

Comment: @eyllanesc well as I move the item around I can clearly see that newPos and rect do no display the same coordinates... For example at the first change, newPos is at (0, 0) but rect is at (70, 70), so when I move the item so rect is at (0, 0), newPos is at (-70, -70).

Comment: Just boundingRect) is in coordinates of the item and pos in coordinates of the scene

Comment: Ok I think I solved my problem, see my answer. thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I think that I have solved my problem. The thing that I forgot to mention is that my item was initialized this way:

```
auto item = new CustomItem(QPolygonF(QRectF(70, 70, 100, 100)));
```

What I did to fix my problem is first initialize the item at (0, 0) and then use QGraphicsItem::moveBy() instead of giving positions to my item's constructor.

```
auto item = new CustomItem(QPolygonF(QRectF(0, 0, 100, 100)));
item->moveBy(70, 70);
```

Now `newPos` and `rect` give me the same coordinates in the `itemChange()` function.